# Merge Multiple Queries Into 1 Query - On the same Row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, union

I have 1 table called itemmovement : It has Item Id , Quantity In , Quantity Out , Invoice Id, Date.
I need to make in one query to show how many pieces are sold and beside the sold column there will be the current on hand quantity .

itemmovement

```
Id   itemid      qtyin     qtyout    invid        date
1     1            10                          2019-01-04
2     2            8                           2019-01-06
3     2                      2         1       2019-01-08
4     1                      3         2       2019-01-12
5     2            1                           2019-02-04
6     3            4                           2019-03-04
7     1                      1         3       2019-04-04
```

I need the query to show this result

```
Id   itemid      Sold Quantity   OnHandQty
1     1               4             6
2     2               2             7
3     3               0             4
```

I'm Trying to use this query but not working

```
SELECT * from (
        SELECT itmv.itemid,sum(itmv.qtyout)-sum(itmv.qtyin)
        FROM itemmovement itmv
        WHERE   ( itmv.systemdate BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-06-01') AND 
                invid>0 
        group by itmv.itemid) as result1,

        (SELECT sum(itmv2.qtyin)-sum(itmv2.qtyout)
        from itemmovement itmv2
        where itmv.itemid=itmv2.itemid
        group by itmv2.itemid) as result2

        order by sum(itmv.qtyin)-sum(itmv.qtyout)
```

Comment: whats not working do you get a error or just plain invalid results?

Comment: I don't understand how you get the valeus of the `Id` column in your result set.  Is it just the row number of the result?  Otherwise I don't see how `Id = 3` gives `itemid = 3`.

Comment: @Martin they are 3 items , so itemid 1 , 2 , 3 . For the Id it is a normal Id for the query it doesn't refer for anything.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  the error I'm getting :

Unknown column 'itmv.itemid' in 'where clause

it for this syntax : where itmv.itemid=itmv2.itemid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want aggregation?

```
select itemid,
       sum(qtyout) as sold_quantity,
       coalesce(sum(qtyin), 0) - coalesce(sum(qtyout), 0) as onhand
from itemmovement itmv
group by itemid;
```

Comment: Columns are interchanged. Sum(qtyout) is sold; while sum(in - out) = onhand

Comment: actually my tables are bigger because i have quantity out related for purchase return , which i have additional column purchasereturnid - field , and the quantities goes under the same quantity out (qtyout) column , so i can't use the query ; it is correct but in my case i can't use , i need to use for the sold quantity , where invid>0 (To get only the sold quantity (qtyout) only )

Comment: @Moussa . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question with more appropriate sample data.

Answer (score 0):

Group by id and aggregate:

```
select
  itemid,
  coalesce(sum(qtyout), 0) `Sold Quantity`,
  coalesce(sum(qtyin), 0) - coalesce(sum(qtyout), 0) OnHandQty
from itemmovement
group by itemid
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5G3DEzkKXLJ7YvHLeM7mZP/0).
Results:

```
| itemid | Sold Quantity | OnHandQty |
| ------ | ------------- | --------- |
| 1      | 4             | 6         |
| 2      | 2             | 7         |
| 3      | 0             | 4         |
```

Comment: actually my tables are bigger because i have quantity out related for purchase return , which i have additional column purchasereturnid and it is under the same quantity out column , so i can't use the query ; it is correct but in my case i can't use , i need to use for the sold quantity , where invid>0 (To get only the sold quantity (qtyout) )

Comment: This answer the question as you posted it. If there is a new reqirement post another question.